# On playwright, the test doesn't show the same error when I execute it with "playwright test" or "playwright test --headed"

Tags: terminal, playwright, end-to-end

I have a problem with playwright and I tried solving it thanks to the debugger --headed (I think the main problem is due to delay that elements need to appear on my page).

The thing is, when I execute the test with "npx playwright test", it shows that my test failed at line 193 while when I execute the test with "npx playwright test --headed" it fails at line 186.

Do you know why this error might occur ?

(Sorry if my english's bad, I'm not native ...)

I tried solving the problem shown at line 186 but there always seem to be a new problem.
It click on the element I am telling to click on. I tried waiting for the element to be visible but it didn't work. I also tried using different type of locating such as text, id, type but it didn't work either.

And I really don't understand why these errors appear only when I put --headed after the test...

Comment: Hey, if we don't know what stays behind any line it would be extremely hard to help you :) Please add a sample of the test so we can spot if something is not right.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. See [Playwright works in headful mode but fails in headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75488727/playwright-works-in-headful-mode-but-fails-in-headless/75489724#75489724).

Comment: Let's share your code, without it it will be difficult to help.