# Playwright Element found but continues to show as hidden

Tags: typescript, playwright

I'm trying to create a basic register script using playwright typescript. If I use debug mode and step through the code it runs perfect but if I use headless, it fails. It fails when trying to do a fill in the email field. The locator that I'm using is able to find the element but it tries to wait for it to be visible even though it's present on the page. There are no iframes on the html.

```
import { test, expect, Locator, Page } from '@playwright/test';



class RegisterStr{
  userName: Locator;
  pw: Locator;
  button: Locator;
  

  constructor(page: Page){
    this.userName = page.locator('#username')
    this.pw = page.getByLabel('#password')
    this.button = page.locator("#submit")
  }
}


test.describe("Resgietring", ()=>{
  let regis : RegisterStr;

  test('has title', async ({ page }) => {
    regis = new RegisterStr(page)
    await page.goto('https://practicetestautomation.com/practice-test-login/');

    regis.userName.fill("student")
    regis.pw.fill("Password123")
    regis.button.click();
  
    // await page.waitForURL("https://practicetestautomation.com/logged-in-successfully/")
  
    // Expect signed in 
    await expect(page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Logged In Successfully' })).toBeVisible();
  });
})
```

[Error Shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emz20.png)

Comment: Please share a [mcve] with complete, runnable code, the site you're scraping, and the desired result. That said, [Playwright works in headful mode but fails in headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75488727/playwright-works-in-headful-mode-but-fails-in-headless) is probably related. Try [changing the user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75489724/6243352) if you haven't yet. Also applicable: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @ggorlen that did not seem to resolve my issue. The code breaks on the fill. It seems like when I try to import a class and do the operation, it fails but if I do it without classs it works.  I've updated to include a reproducible example

Comment: Thanks. One immediate problem is that there's no `await` in front of most of your Playwright calls, like `regis.userName.fill("student")`. I'd start by adding those--they're non-negotiable. Beyond that, using `locator` rather than `getByLabel` passes the test for me, headfully or headlessly.

Comment: thank you so much! you've earned a follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. You need to `await` all Playwright API calls that return promises. Failing to do so causes race conditions and nondeterminism, meaning the script can fail at random and give confusing errors or unpredictable behavior.
2. When passing a CSS selector into a locator, use `.locator()` rather than `.getByLabel()`.

Applying these fixes passes the test for me headfully or headlessly (I used JS, not TS but it's irrelevant):

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

class Register {
  constructor(page) {
    this.userName = page.locator("#username");
    this.pw = page.locator("#password");
    this.button = page.locator("#submit");
  }
}

test.describe("Registering", () => {
  test("has title", async ({page}) => {
    const regis = new Register(page);
    await page.goto(
      "https://practicetestautomation.com/practice-test-login/"
    );
    await regis.userName.fill("student");
    await regis.pw.fill("Password123");
    await regis.button.click();
    await page.waitForURL(
      "https://practicetestautomation.com/logged-in-successfully/"
    );
    await expect(
      page.getByRole("heading", {name: "Logged In Successfully"})
    ).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

Beyond correctness, the [POM](https://playwright.dev/docs/pom) here should probably be doing more work than it currently is. It's inconsistent to have some locators in the POM and some not, and generally it's useful to add methods that abstract away some of the "raw" Playwright actions.