# How to handle google signup popup in playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright

When I debug my code it works perfectly fine but when I run it gives me the error.
Code:

```
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test("test", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://sma-fe.aa-qa.global-drum.com/login");

  await page.getByRole("button", { name: "Login With Google" }).click();
  const page1Promise = page.waitForEvent("popup");
  const page1 = await page1Promise;
  await page1
    .getByLabel("Email or phone")
    .fill("testing@tempmail.com");
  await page1.getByLabel("Email or phone").press("Enter");
  await page1.getByLabel("Enter your password").fill("user123@");
  await page1.getByLabel("Enter your password").press("Enter");
  await page.goto("https://sma-fe.aa-qa.global-drum.com/communities");
  await page
    .getByRole("columnheader", { name: "Company" })
    .getByRole("textbox")
    .click();
});
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYv0r.png)

Comment: Did you try running it in headful mode to see what the browser looks like?

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Usually, you need to begin listening for the popup event, then trigger the action that causes it, then await the popup. Also, the code in your error and your actual code are different. Please clarify. If your code works in headful mode but not headless, you might try [adding a user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75489724/6243352).

Comment: @hardkoded Yes i tried running it in headfull mode. It opens the website but it do not clicks on the google login button.

Comment: @ggorlen I just changed the call for pagePromis before calling the click event.
Can you give me some video link where I can see how to add user agent.