# Browser headful mode at Linux for web scraping

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, browser, playwright, bypass

https://swappie.com/en/iphone/ we managed to bypass the Cloudflare protection page if we use a *proxy* and a *browser in the headful mode* (both with Chrome headless in Selenium and Chromium
in Playwright). But on the Linux server we can run browser only as headless.
**Do you have any ideas how to break thru ?**

Comment: Canonical for Playwright: [Playwright works in headful mode but fails in headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75488727/playwright-works-in-headful-mode-but-fails-in-headless/75489724#75489724). Please confirm you've added a browser user agent. If you're still blocked after that, please share a minimal reproducible example of your code and your package.json. If you're using Playwright Python, please tag accordingly and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887356/headless-doesnt-work-using-playwright-and-beautifulsoup-4/72999870#72999870). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Linux tool called `Xvfb`, which creates a virtual display so that you don't have to use Chrome's headless mode when running browser tests in it. Various frameworks have a option to use it.

Here's a sample [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) script that bypasses the Cloudflare Turnstile page on a popular site:

```py
"""SB Manager using UC Mode for evading bot-detection."""
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, test=True, xvfb=True) as sb:
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://top.gg/", 5)
    if not sb.is_text_visible("Discord Bots", "h1"):
        sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://top.gg/", 5)
    sb.assert_text("Discord Bots", "h1", timeout=3)
    sb.highlight("h1", loops=3)
    sb.set_messenger_theme(location="top_center")
    sb.post_message("Selenium wasn't detected!", duration=3)
```

It also works in Linux (assuming that the IP Address you have wasn't blocked already).